# How to get EKEvent Attached files to a meeting

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit, ekevent

Is there a way to get attachments from a calendar event? I am talking about EKEvent. I see that iOS Calendar shows the attachments as follows:

[image]

But I cannot find anything in the EKEvent or EKCalendarItem that shows me how I can get the meeting attachments. Please help if you know how.

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a way.